# Why group capturing extract eveything in str_replace in r

Tags: r, regex

**Context**

```
a = 'g_pm10year1126.81 - 139.90'
```

I have a character vector `a`. I want to extract the content after `year1` in the string `a` (`"126.81 - 139.90"`).

By using `str_extract(a, "(? <=year1).*")` I successfully extracted the content I wanted.

After that, I tried to use group capturing in the `str_replace` function, but it returned the whole string `a`.

**Question**

My question is why `str_replace(a, "(? <=year1)(. *)", '\\1')` returns `"g_pm10year1126.81 - 139.90"`.

As I understand it it should return `126.81 - 139.90`.

Reproducible code:

```
library(stringr)

a = 'g_pm10year1126.81 - 139.90'

> str_extract(a, "(?<=year1).*")
[1] "126.81 - 139.90"

> str_replace(a, "(?<=year1)(.*)", '\\1')
[1] "g_pm10year1126.81 - 139.90"
```

Comment: Have you read about [how capturing works?](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) To get same results using `str_replace` you would not need a lookbehind, just [replace `^.*?year1(.*)` with `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/0QWvAM/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are replacing the captured group with itself. Hence you are not changing anything and end up with your input string.

To achieve your desired result using `str_replace` you have to replace the part before the captured group, i.e. you could do:

```r
library(stringr)

a = 'g_pm10year1126.81 - 139.90'

str_replace(a, "^.*?(?<=year1)(.*)", '\\1')
#> [1] "126.81 - 139.90"
```